# Sort WooCommerce cross-sells by date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, cart

Woocommerce cross-sells are displayed on cart page. By default they are sorted randomly. Can anyone please help me to sort them by date (= publishing date of product)? Thanks very much!

Here is the content of cross-sells.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * Cross-sells
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cross-sells.php.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( $cross_sells ) : ?>

    <div class="cross-sells">

        <h2><?php _e( 'You may be interested in&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) ?></h2>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php foreach ( $cross_sells as $cross_sell ) : ?>

                <?php
                    $post_object = get_post( $cross_sell->get_id() );

                    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

***HERE is the SOLUTION:***

You do NOT have to edit cross-sells.php ! Instead you can create a little plugin that does the job:

1. Putt the following code into a new php file.
2. Upload it to your WP plugin folder.
3. Activate the plugin in WP backend.
4. Test the results on your cart page. Your cross-sells will be ordered by publishing date now.
5. If you want to change the order manually, you can simply change the publishing date via WP backend on product page for each product.

Thanks to LoicTheAztec for providing the filter-hook for this solution!
(By creating a plugin for this filter-hook you do not have to edit function.php or create a child theme.)

Here is the code for this little plugin:

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name: Woocommerce Sort Cross-sales by Date
* Description: This plugin is used to sort cross-sells by date
* Author: ARaction GmbH with help of LoicTheAztec - no guarantee or support!
* Version: 0.1
*/

/* Your code goes below here. */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_orderby', 'custom_cross_sells_orderby', 10, 1 );
function custom_cross_sells_orderby( $orderby ){
    $orderby = 'date';
    return $orderby;
}
/* Your code goes above here. */

?>
```

Comment: Just after the `if ( $cross_sells ) : `, could you do a `print_r( $cross_sells )` and add the output to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order cross sells by date you can use this filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_orderby', 'custom_cross_sells_orderby', 10, 1 );
function custom_cross_sells_orderby( $orderby ){
    $orderby = 'date';
    return $orderby;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Works like a charm!